# Click on link without the basic message

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

How to do that when you click on the link did not work event.
Example:

HTML

```
<div><p onclick='location.href=/link_site'>message and link http://example.com/abcde</p></div>
```

I clicked http://example.com/abcde and working location.href, how to make when you press on the link to the event did not work location.href?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are working inside PHP (or other language?), you do not need the backslashes to escape the double-quotes.

Escaping tells the processor/server to read the next character as a literal entry instead of instruction code. (This is not a technical explanation).

In HTML5, you don't need single or double quotes, but it is good form to contain your information.

`<div><p onclick='location.href=link_site'>message and link http://example.com/abcde</p></div>`

Comment: Yes, this just example.

Comment: I added a tag for PHP.  What is the variable for the link_site?  It must be `$link_site` to reference it in PHP.

Comment: Okay ... not PHP, then what it is it?

Comment: You can edit the question and remove the tag for PHP.

Comment: Post your solution, please.

Answer (score 0):

No.For blocking click event or something like this,there are ideas called preventDefault and stopPropagation.You can search those names and read what do these mean.Here is a link of click events.maybe it can help you.

http://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/javascript-events.html